# GWT attached pdf document in post response

Tags: java, gwt

I have an issue with http response.
I send some data and in response I get attached pdf document, and I need to open it document in a new browser tab.

I can't do it using `Window.Open(String url, String title, String... parameters)` because I dont have this url.

---

[image]

if I open it with right click on and tell firebug "Open in a new Tab" I got an url

Comment: I can't do it using Window.Open(String url, String title, String... parameters) because I dont have this url.

Comment: How do you POST the data? I gather you don't use a <form>, but if you did you could supply the 'target' attribute to the form to open the response in a new window. If you're submitting the data with AJAX, it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display pdf in your page you should have `Content-Type: application/pdf` in your response header. So, You should set in response header in your servlet which is responsible that given url.
After that you can put your pdf inside one of these html tags embed, object or iframe. I think gwt's [Frame](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html) is a good way to do it. See this tutorial as well: [4 Ways To Stream Pdf and Some Tips](http://www.techper.net/2008/02/27/4-ways-to-stream-pdf-and-some-tips/)

Comment: Sorry, but I send an xml request (post) and in response I have pdf document generated with some service, I can't use a simple link or reference a frame to a simple url.

Comment: do you mean your service generates a `ByteArrayOutputStream` ?